Ubuntu on Virtual Box does not access Windows 11 Wi-Fi network
I am trying to install VirtualBox on Windows 11, and Ubuntu on VirtualBox does not access the Windows 11 Wi-Fi network. As indicated bellow on the image
enter image description here

Are you using Ubuntu 14.04? It is more than 10 years old!!!! If I remember correctly, VirtualBox creates a virtual environment that includes a virtual Ethernet cable connection irrespective of whether you have wired or Wireless connection to the host Windows computer.

Bridged Adapter
This mode is used to connect a virtual machine's virtual network adapter to a physical network to which a physical network adapter of the VirtualBox host machine is connected. A VM virtual network adapter uses the host's network interface for a network connection. Simply put, network packets are sent and received directly from/to the virtual network adapter without additional routing. VirtualBox uses a special network filter driver for bridged network mode to filter data from the host's physical network adapter.
This network mode can be used to run servers on virtual machines that must be fully accessible from a physical local area network. When using bridged network mode in VirtualBox, a host machine, hosts on the physical network, and external networks including the Internet can be accessed from a VM. The virtual machine can be accessed from the host machine and from other hosts (and virtual machines) connected to the physical network.
